# Asynchronous fetch request with Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm reading the documentation for [asynchronous fetch requests](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/asynchronousrequests) in GAE. Python isn't my first language, so I'm having trouble finding out what would be best for my case. I don't really need or care about the response for the request, I just need it to send the request and forget about it and move on to other tasks.

So I tried code like in the documentation:

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch

rpc = urlfetch.create_rpc()
urlfetch.make_fetch_call(rpc, "http://www.google.com/")

# ... do other things ...

try:
    result = rpc.get_result()
    if result.status_code == 200:
        text = result.content
        # ...
except urlfetch.DownloadError:
    # Request timed out or failed.
    # ...
```

But this code doesn't work unless I include `try:` and `except`, which I really don't care for. Omitting that part makes the request not go through though.

What is the best option for creating fetch requests where I don't care for the response, so that it just begins the request, and moves on to whatever other tasks there are, and never looks back?

Comment: What happens when you omit the try/except? Do you get a traceback? Is the DownloadError always raised?

Comment: Is this on the production server, or dev_appserver that you're noticing the requests not getting sent?

Comment: It's on the dev server, but Moishie below says that it's the get_result() that's making the fetch go through, which I was omitting hoping that way I wouldn't have to wait for a response

Comment: The dev server is single-threaded; it doesn't do asynchronous requests at all; the request is actually made when you call `get_result()` or `wait()`.

Comment: I don't get it..what's all this talk about rpc and async requests in the documentation then?

Comment: On the production servers, urlfetch is a service provided by another machine somewhere at google. Your application makes an RPC to the urlfetch service, which makes the HTTP request to the external host and returns the result, either synchronously or asynchronously. When using the development server, there's no urlfetch service running on your machine to make an RPC to; the single-threaded dev_appserver makes all of the requests itself.

Comment: I ended up using task queues. Is this a better option than RPC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do your tasks where the

```
# ... do other things ...
```

comment is. When you are otherwise finished, then call `rpc.wait()`. Note that it's not the `try/except` that's making it work, it's the `get_result()` call. That can be replaced with `wait()`.

So your code would look like this:

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch

rpc = urlfetch.create_rpc()
urlfetch.make_fetch_call(rpc, "http://www.google.com/")

# ... do other things ... << YOUR CODE HERE

rpc.wait()
```

Comment: Well the thing is, the "do other things" part, I want to send out a server response with some data, so that won't be sent out until the rpc urlfetch is finished, no? And what if the urlfetch is in a separate function? So I would call do_async_request(), then how could I do things after that function call?

Comment: If you want to respond, then set up your urlfetch in a task queue instead.

Comment: (a) I think Moishe meant "rpc.wait()"; (b) there is no way to return a response to the user before all your RPCs (synchronous or async) have run till completion or timed out. So yes, if you are making a urlfetch call that you think is slow and you don't want th euser to have to wait for it, put it in the task queue. The deferred module might be handy for this simple case. In the taks, don't bother to use the async API.

Comment: Guido's right; I fixed the code. This is why I like getting Guido as a code reviewer when I can :)

Answer (score 4):

If you don't care about the response, the response may take a while, and you don't want your handler to wait for it to complete before returning a response to the user, you may want to consider firing off a [task queue](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/) task that makes the request rather than doing it within your user-facing handler.