# GAE - How can I combine the results of several asynchronous url fetches?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, urlfetch

I have a Google `AppEngine` (in `Python`) application where I need to perform 4 to 5 url fetches, and then combine the data before I print it out to the response.

I can do this without any problems using a synchronous workflow, but since the urls that I am fetching are not related or dependent on each other, performing this asynchronously would be the most ideal (and quickest).

I have read and re-read the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/asynchronousrequests#Making_Asynchronous_Requests), but I just can't figure out how to get read the contents for each url. I've also searched the web for a small example (which is really what I am in need of). I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107825/asynchronous-fetch-request-with-google-app-engine) SO question, but again, here they don't mention anything about reading the contents of these individual asynchronous url fetches.

Does anyone have any simple examples of how to perform 4 or 5 asynchronous url fetches with AppEngine? And then combine the results before I print it to the response?

Here is what I have so far:

```
rpcs = []
for album in result_object['data']:
  total_facebook_photo_count = total_facebook_photo_count + album['count']
  facebook_albumid_array.append(album['id'])

  #Get the photos in the photo album
  facebook_photos_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/%s/photos?access_token=%s&limit=1000' % (album['id'], access_token)

  rpc = urlfetch.create_rpc()
  urlfetch.make_fetch_call(rpc, facebook_photos_url)
  rpcs.append(rpc)

for rpc in rpcs:
  result = rpc.get_result()
  self.response.out.write(result.content)
```

However, it still looks like the line: result = rpc.get_result() is forcing it to wait for the first request to finish, then the second, then the third, and so forth. Is there a way to simply put the results in a variables as they are received?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [example](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/asynchronousrequests#Making_Asynchronous_Requests), `text = result.content` is where you get the content (body).

To do url fetches in parallell, you could set them up, add to a list and check results afterwards. Expanding on the example already mentioned, it could look something like:

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch

futures = []
for url in urls:
    rpc = urlfetch.create_rpc()
    urlfetch.make_fetch_call(rpc, url)
    futures.append(rpc)

contents = []
for rpc in futures:
    try:
        result = rpc.get_result()
        if result.status_code == 200:
            contents.append(result.content)
            # ...
    except urlfetch.DownloadError:
        # Request timed out or failed.
        # ...

concatenated_result = '\n'.join(contents)
```

In this example, we assemble the body of all the requests that returned status code 200, and concatenate with linebreak between them.

Or with [ndb](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/async#urlfetch), my personal preference for anything async on GAE, something like:

```
@ndb.tasklet
def get_urls(urls):
  ctx = ndb.get_context()
  result = yield map(ctx.urlfetch, urls)
  contents = [r.content for r in result if r.status_code==200]
  raise ndb.Return('\n'.join(contents))
```

Comment: Wow, seeing this really helped! Thanks! I'll check out ndb also :-)

Answer (score 1):

I use this code (*implmented before I learned about ndb tasklets*):

```
    while rpcs:
      rpc = UserRPC.wait_any(rpcs)
      result = rpc.get_result()
      # process result here
      rpcs.remove(rpc)
```